# Can't figure out what is wrong with my code

Tags: java, string, methods, static-methods

This is the instructions i got from my teacher:

Write your code in the file `WordCount.java`. Your code should go into a method with the following signature. You may write your own main method to test your code. The graders will ignore your main method:

```
public static int countWords(String original, int minLength){}
```

Your method should count the number of words in the sentence that meet or exceed minLength (in letters). For example, if the minimum length given is 4, your program should only count words that are at least 4 letters long.

Words will be separated by one or more spaces. Non-letter characters (spaces, punctuation, digits, etc.) may be present, but should not count towards the length of words.

Hint: write a method that counts the number of letters (and ignores punctuation) in a string that holds a single word without spaces. In your countWords method, break the input string up into words and send each one to your method.

**This is my code:**

```
public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter string: ");
        String input = IO.readString();
        System.out.print("Enter minimum length for letter: ");
        int length = IO.readInt();
        IO.outputIntAnswer(countWords(input, length));
    }
    public static int countWords(String original, int minLegth)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int letterCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++)
        {
            char temp = original.charAt(i);
            if(temp >= 'A' && temp <= 'Z' || temp >= 'a' && temp <= 'z')
            {
                letterCount++;
            }
            else if(temp == ' '|| i == original.length()-1)
            {
                if(letterCount >= minLegth)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                letterCount = 0;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

My college uses an autograder to grade project and i am keep getting one of the test case wrong. Can someone help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Which test cases have you tried this with?

Comment: Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask].  This type of question (code dump and "can't figure out what's wrong" with no other details) is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem that your code is not able to compare the last character.It expects a space after the last character so that it can compare the last character since java doesn't use null character terminator for string termination.I have emulated the same code using Scanner class as I was having some trouble with io.So I have done the following change:

```
         Scanner sc1,sc2;
        sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
         String input = sc1.nextLine()+" ";
```

I don't know if its possible to do:

```
String input = IO.readString()+" ";
```

but i think you should try appending blank space " " at the end of the string